# ruby merge two hash by same key and same values

Tags: ruby, hash

Note: that the two hashes has the with same key and the same values

```
a = {:ip=>'192.168.2.1',:b=>2}
b = {:ip=>'192.168.2.1',:c=>4}
```

i want to merge them to a new hash like this

```
newhash= {:ip=>'192.168.2.1',:b=>2,:c=4}
```

Comment: Your hash is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
a = {:ip=>"192.168.2.1", :b=>2}
b = {:ip=>"192.168.2.1", :c=>4}
newhash = a.merge(b)
#=> {:ip=>"192.168.2.1", :b=>2, :c=>4}
```